# Symfony 1.4, Doctrine: how to get the lastest "joined" record?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

An user has more tasks, 1 : N connection.

Visually:

```
admin
 task1 2011/01/01 00:00:01
 task2 2011/01/01 00:00:04
 task3 2011/01/01 00:00:02
user2
 task1 2011/03/01 00:01:01
 task2 2011/03/01 00:01:04
 task3 2011/03/01 00:01:02
```

(see the schema from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14071955/569101))

How to left join the user and the last "task", not get all of them?

The matter is I dont know how to do it with pure SQL... I saw some example here, but they are not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we consider that you have the user id inside `$user_id` and according to your schema in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14071955/569101), you can try this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.*, t.*')
    ->from('User u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Task t')
    ->where('t.id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM Task t2 WHERE t2.owner_id = ? ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1)', array($user_id));
$res = $q->execute();
```

Here is [the documentation for subqueries](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries) in Doctrine.

Comment: Complicated, I rather chosen to solve it with one more query :)

Comment: That's another solution, I sometimes prefer to use less queries :-)